# iPad HTML audio detect `load`

Tags: ipad, html, audio

I want to detect when audio has loaded on iPad. My code loads, and plays the mp3, but the event listener never fires.

```
        $mp3.load()
        $mp3.addEventListener("load", function() {
            alert('Happy days') // <~~ this never fires
        }, true)
        $mp3.play()
```

I am using iOS 4.2. I am aware that all of this might not work on the latest iOS, and I don't mind that.

Comment: Is this using an `audio` element?

Comment: yes, `$mp3` is a reference to the audio element itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an event listener for canplaythrough, e.g.

`addEventListener("canplaythrough", this.onLoad.bind(this), false);`

Then once it triggers, remove it so you wont get it again:

`onLoad:function ()
{
  arguments.callee.removeEventListener("canplaythrough", this.onLoad.bind(this), false);
  // do something
}`